# How to insert scraped data using flask_sqlalchemy models?

Tags: python, flask

To be able to easily use flask-paginate, I switched to Flask-SQLAlchemy in my Flask app. However, this is my first time using something like this, and I'm having some issues understanding what it is I need to do to insert scraped content into my database now.

Previously, I appended scraped content, and then used that to save it to my database. For example:

```
# previous code to access tables
jobs = []
for row in tables:
    jobs.append({
        'title': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.classhere').text,
        'info': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.classhere').text,
        'location': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.classhere').text,
        'link': row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.classhere').get_attribute('href'),
     })
```

And then, with that, I did:

```
for job in jobs:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO jobs(title, info, location, link) VALUES(?,?,?,?)''',
              (job['title'], job['info'], job['location'], job['link']))
conn.commit()
```

I wrote the table inside the schema.sql file and then ran init_db.py to create it. To get the information, it was pretty straightforward as well.

After I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-flask-sqlalchemy-to-interact-with-databases-in-a-flask-application), and installed flask_sqlalchemy and created a model that looks like this:

```
class Job(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    info = db.Column(db.Text)
    location = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    link = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, title, info, location, link):
        self.title = title
        self.info = info
        self.location = location
        self.link = link

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Job {self.title}>'
```

Then created it with db.create_all() via terminal, and added a `jobs = Job.query.all()` to my home route. Now I can't figure out how I should change the above code so that when I'm running my scraping scripts (Selenium), it adds the scraped data to the database? I know I'm missing some information here, and though it might be simple, I can't connect the dots. All the other tutorials I found just use the terminal and insert dummy data that way, which is not what I need here. What do I need to write to accomplish the above scraping and inserting code? Do I just use a similar approach with execute and `INSERT INTO` as I did above, or is there something else I should be doing? I'm having trouble searching for similar examples (no idea what else to type), so even a link could help me a lot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor for your model is not necessary.

```py
class Job(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    info = db.Column(db.Text)
    location = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    link = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Job {self.title}>'
```

To add the data to the database, you need an [application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/appcontext/). In this you create instances of the model, which are added to the session. Calling `commit()` commits the session to the database. If an error is thrown, all actions are rolled back using `rollback()`.

```py
def insert_jobs(jobs):
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.add_all([Job(**job) for job in jobs])
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except: 
            db.session.rollback()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Detlef. I know how to approach this and what to research now.